# JS Split ( ) to check if substring exists in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I have an `array` of products that are stored as `Strings` in this format `productname:quantity`. The issue I am running into is that if a user adds one product with a quantity of x it is inserted into the `array` as it should. However, if they then decide to add more of a particular product a new entry is made into the `array` instead of checking if the product already exists and adjusting the quantity to the new value. `oldQty + newQty`.

For example this is my array:

```
["CBL202659/A:1","OUTER9:1","PALLET CARDS:1"]
```

If I add another PALLET CARDS product it creates a new entry rather than updating the quantity of the existing item to 2.

New array

```
["CBL202659/A:1","OUTER9:1","PALLET CARDS:1","PALLET CARDS:1"]
```

I would like the array to end up like this: - updating the quantity

```
["CBL202659/A:1","OUTER9:1","PALLET CARDS:2"]
```

Currently this is my code:

I use the `split()` method to seperate the String where a colon occurs and store the product name and quantity in two seperate variables.

```
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){

        //Show the order Box
        $(".order-alert").show();
        event.preventDefault();

        //Create the Array
        var productArray = [];  

        //Get reference to the product clicked
        var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();       
        //Get reference to the quantity selected
        var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();
        var item = stockCode + ":" + quantity;
        var itemCheck = stockCode + ":";

        if(quantity == 0){
            console.log("Quantity must be greater than 0")
        }else{
            //If no Cookie exists, create one and add the Array
            if ($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined) {
                console.log("CREATE NEW COOKIE");
                //Add items to Array
                productArray.push(item);
                //Add Array to Cookie
                $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });

            //If the Cookie already exists do this  
            } else {
                productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));//get ref to array

                if(productArray.indexOf(itemCheck)!= -1){//It exists so update qty
                console.log("EXISTS... updating item: " + itemCheck);
                            //var index = productArray.indexOf(item);
                            //var update = productArray[index].split(":");
                            //var name = update[0];
                            //var oldQty = update[1];
                            //console.log(name + ":" + oldQty);
                            //productArray[index] = item;
                }else{//It does not exist, so add to array
                console.log("Does not exist... adding new item: " + item);
                 //Append items onto the Array
                 productArray.push(item);
                }

                //Update the Cookie
                $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
                console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
            }

            //Display the number of items in the Array in the Order Box
            $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
        }
    });
```

I suppose the real question I am asking here, is if it is possible to search the `array` for a `subString` - containing `productname:` ??

After taking on board some of the answers and advice I've slightly modified how I am structuring my `array`.

However I am running into issues regarding the name value pair.

Step 1: Get references to the stockCode and Quantity

```
            //Create the Array
        var productArray = [];
        //Get reference to the product clicked
        var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
        //Get reference to the quantity selected
        var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();
```

print them in console to make sure they are correct

```
PALLET CARDS
2
```

Step 2: Insert them into the Array

```
    productArray.push({stockCode:quantity});
```

print them to make sure they are correct - NO - Problem here...

```
[Object]
0: Object
stockCode: "2"    <---------------------- Should be PALLET CARDS: "2"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Consider rearranging your structure. An object like `{"CBL202659/A":1, "OUTER9":1, "PALLET CARDS": 1}` would be *much* easier to work with.

Comment: `var item = stockCode + ":" + quantity;` is the code where I build the `String` to go into the `array`. How would I modify this to match your suggested structure?

Comment: Spot the problem: "I have an array of products that are stored as Strings." ;-)

Comment: @Javacadabra I've updated my answer for the option of using your original string array.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var input  = ["CBL202659/A:1","OUTER9:1","PALLET CARDS:1","PALLET CARDS:1"],
    dict   = {},
    output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var parts = input[i].split(':');
  if (dict[parts[0]] == undefined) {
    dict[parts[0]] = 0;
  }

  dict[parts[0]] += +parts[1];
}

for (var key in dict) {
  output.push([key, dict[key]].join(':'));
}
```

Output:

```
["CBL202659/A:1", "OUTER9:1", "PALLET CARDS:2"]
```

However, as `Niet the Dark Absol` mentioned, you should end up with `dict` object which looks like:

```
Object {CBL202659/A: 1, OUTER9: 1, PALLET CARDS: 2}
```

and gives you more power to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes a lot of sense and I can see the advantages to using a `dictionary` object over the standard `array`. Would converting my current `array` to an object of this type be a large amount of work as I've got 3 `scripts` working with this `array`

Comment: @Javacadabra I do not know, how much work it will takes, however I think it's worth the price.

Comment: @Javacadabra You are creating the Array yourself from your HTML, so you don't need to create the dictionary from the Array, just make it a key/pair object from the start..

Comment: Yes I am working on that @webkit, however running into an issue. I've updated my code in OP if you care to have a look

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
  var item = stockCode + ":" + quantity;
  var itemCheck = stockCode + ":";
  ...
```

just do this:

EDIT: Also to check if stock exists already I think this will work...

```
function checkCode() {
    for (var i=0; i<productArray.length;i++) {
         if (p[i].stockcode==stockCode) {
            p[i].amount+= parseInt(quantity) 
        }
    }

}

if (!checkCode()) productArray.push({ stockcode: stockCode, amount:parseInt(quantity)});
```

---

If you decide to stay with your original string array.. this could work for you:

```
var pArray = ["CBL202659/A:1","OUTER9:1","PALLET CARDS:1"];


for (var i =0; i<pArray.length;i++) {
    var code =  pArray[i].split(":")[0];
    var amount = parseInt(pArray[i].split(":")[1]);

    if (code==stockCode) {
        // code already exists
        amount += parseInt(quantity);
        pArray[i] = code+":"+amount;
    } 
}
```

and then use this in a function like the example above..

Comment: I will try and implement this now, thank you very much @webkit